# Is it necessary to unmount state within ComponentWillUnmount?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance, react-native

I'm  performing server requests in my app within `componentDidMount`.So I'm calling `setState` within `componentDidMount`.Do I need to unmount this `state` within `componentWillUnmount` ?Is this is a solution for avoiding memory leaks in my app ?Please help me to find a solution for this.Thank you!

**sample code**

```
componentDidMount(){
  fetch({ /* ... */ })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then((responseData) => {
      this.setState({
        result: responseData.meta.data
      })
    })
}

componentWillUnmount(){
  this.setState({
    result:''
  })
}
```

Comment: The component state will be cleaned up automatically on unmount, so you don't need to use `setState` in `componentWillUnmount`.

Comment: Nope, it is not necessary in this case. However, if you use some `timeout` functions then you have to clear them before unmounting your component.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not needed to unmount the state. Setting `result` to empty string isn't any better than setting it to any other value.

The cause of memory leaks is that a reference to an object (component instance) is used somewhere, this prevents it from being garbage-collected as unused.

In this piece of code `setState` can be called after the component is unmounted because the request isn't cancelled. This will cause a warning:

> Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the componentWillUnmount method.

In case a request is long enough, this will cause a memory leak. In order to avoid it, a request or a promise that causes `setState` call needs to be cancelled. As for Fetch API request, can be done with [`AbortController`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortController/abort).

Answer (score 0):

React cleans the state of the component upon unmounting, so you don't have to reset the state on componentWillUnmount.

Something that *can* happen with performing request in components, is that your request can be completed *after* your component is unmounted again. At that point you're trying to perform setState on a component that isn't mounted. You'll receive an error in your console at that point. 
Most HTTP libraries offer functionalities to cancel requests, this can be used to prevent that from happening. [An example from the axios library here...](https://github.com/axios/axios#cancellation)

Answer (score 0):

You  wouldnt have to worry about cleaning up state while unmounting, as the reasons are already being highlighted by the people above.

But if you have left the listeners attached to your component "unremoved", then that might be a possible candidate for memory leak.
`componentDidMount()` can be used as a place to attach listeners and `componentWillUnmount` to remove those attached listeners.'

In `Flux` architecture, we use them to attach and remove listeners for events emitted from `stores`.

```
public componentDidMount() {
    sampleStore.addListener('sampleEventFired', this.oncatch);
}

public componentWillUnmount() {
    sampleStore.removeListener('sampleEventFired', this.oncatch);
}
```